# find the upper and lower bound of recursive function

Tags: recursive-algorithms

I need you to answer this for me:

> Give an upper and lower bound to this recursive function.
>   $$T(h) = T\left(n^{2/3}\right) +20$$

I tried the iterative method and got stuck.
is it possible to just guess the answer and prove it by induction?

Comment: Did you mean T(n) = T(n^{2/3}) + 20? And what is your base case?

Comment: yes and the base case is T(1) = 1

Comment: By looking at the recursive call, it is impossible to reach the base case. Even though, I tried solving it and ended up with the equation $T(n) = T(n^{(\frac{2}{3})^i}) + 20i$ using the iterative variable $i$. For the base case you defined, I had to solve $n^{(\frac{2}{3})^i} = 1$. But this has no solution. Therefore, the base case is unreachable.

Comment: i have a mistake the base case is T(d) =d for every consistent d